# Why is my database arraylist population algorithm throwing an error?

Tags: java, swing, derby

This is my populate account method which takes the values from my database columns and stores them within an arraylist of objects of the account class that i made which has fields like username and password.
The second part of the code will show if you scroll down

```
private ArrayList<account> populateAccount() throws SQLException{
      Connection c = DatabaseUtilityClass.createNewConnection();
      ArrayList<account> list = new ArrayList();
      try{
          String q = "Select * from LOGIN";
          Statement stmt = (Statement)c.createStatement();
          try(ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(q)){
              while(rs.next()){
                  account a = new account();
                  a.setUsername(rs.getString("USERNAME"));
                  a.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
                  list.add(a);
              }
          }
      }
      catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("err");
      }
      c.close();
        return list;
    }
```

This is the second part of my code which should store the arraylist of objects filled with the database info and then take user text and use a for each loop to iterate through each object checking if the username and password values are the same as the one the user entered via a jTextfield and password field. The errors are on the bottom.

```
 private void LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
try {
    accountCheck= populateAccount();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LoginPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
    String username = user.getText();
    String password = pass.getText();
    for (account a:accountCheck) {
        if(a.getUsername().equals(username) && a.getPassword().equals(password)){
            JPanel p = (JPanel)this.getParent();
    CardLayout c = (CardLayout)p.getLayout();
    c.show(p, PanelConstants.Home);
        }
    }

} 


java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at boomiautomationapp.account.<init>(account.java:21)
    at boomiautomationapp.LoginPage.populateAccount(LoginPage.java:50)
    at boomiautomationapp.LoginPage.LoginActionPerformed(LoginPage.java:146)
    at boomiautomationapp.LoginPage.access$000(LoginPage.java:28)
    at boomiautomationapp.LoginPage$1.actionPerformed(LoginPage.java:94)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Stacktrace says to look somewhere else. Read it. `boomiautomationapp.account.<init>(account.java:21)`

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)